# How to get proportion of two pandas df

Tags: pandas

I have a following problem. I have two datasets:

```py
TableA = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                    'views': [10, 10, 20, 25, 25] })
    
TableB = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
```

I would like to know how many % of views from TableA are presented in TableB. In this case the result will be 30/55, because A and B are presented in TableA (views 10+20) and total sum of vies per category is 55 (10+20+25).

Is there any elegant way how to do this in pandas? I don`t want to "drop duplicates" in both tables and than to use some "antijoin".

Answer (score 1):

You can do `drop_duplicates`

```
s = TableA.drop_duplicates('c')
s.loc[s.c.isin(TableB.c),'views'].sum()/s.views.sum()
Out[51]: 0.5454545454545454
```